# Solving for the Random Variable X in a Z score

Tags: probability, statistics

I know I am going to hate myself when I find out the method of doing this is trivial. Anyways the problem is this. Let X be normally distributed with mean of 120 and standard deviation of 8. Find the interval such that 50% of the data values fall within. I Know that you have to do $\phi(z_2) -\phi(z_1)$ where $z_2=\dfrac{X_1-120}{\sigma}$ and $z_1=\dfrac{X_2-120}{\sigma}$ I know that this will be equal to $0.5$ and I also know that $0.5$ corresponds to a $z$ score of $0$. So how do I manipulate this to solve for $X_1 $ and $X_2$

Comment: Can you not use $X\leq 120$ or $X\geq 120$?

Comment: What do you mean? I am looking for a specific interval that 50% of the data values will lie in

Comment: There are many such intervals. Two simple ones are $[-\infty,120]$ and $[120,\infty]$. If you start at $a < 120$ instead of at $-\infty$, it'll have to go a bit *past* 120, to make up for the elements within $[-\infty,a)$ that you've now excluded. Are you maybe looking for an interval that lies *symmetrically* around 120, i.e. an interval of the form $[120-d,120+d]$?

Comment: yes that is exactly what I am looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requiring that $\Pr[L \le X \le U] = 0.5$ does not uniquely specify the interval $[L,U]$:

[image]

Here, $X \sim {\rm Normal}(\mu = 120, \sigma = 8)$, and we can clearly see that there are infinitely many intervals that contain half of the total area under the density.  If we assume you want the interval that is **symmetric about the mean**, i.e., $\Pr[120-\delta \le X \le 120+\delta] = 0.5$, then standardizing gives $$0.5 = \Pr\left[-\frac{\delta}{8} \le \frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} \le \frac{\delta}{8}\right],$$ and it follows that we wish to find $z^* = \delta/8$ such that $\Pr[Z \le z^*] = 0.25 + 0.5 = 0.75$, or $$z^* = 0.67449.$$  Therefore, $\delta = 5.39592$, and the desired symmetric interval about $\mu = 120$ is $[114.604,125.396]$.

Answer (score 1):

Recall The Empirical Rule : 68% of your data falls within 1 standard deviation of the mean. Now if you want 50% of your data falls within some standard deviation of the mean. call this t. Solve for t. This means the total area of the graph between z = 0 and z = t is 0.25 which means P(0 < z < t) = 0.25. From this you can find t. I look up the table in Triola book and it gives t = 0.68. So (x - 120)/8 = 0.68 ==> x(2) = 125.44. Also solve for the other end value: (x - 120)/8 = -0.68 ==> x(1) = 114.56. So the interval is:
[114.56, 125.44]